# Magento product listing database query

Tags: magento2, product, sql, query

I'm looking for the exact SQL query that lists products - or at least a list of tables which it hits. I was looking for it in the source code, but could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

you can add this to the `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` file:

```
echo $_productCollection->getSelect();
```

this should print the query on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, however, there is not such path for me. No `code` in `app`. Using Magento ver. 2.0.4.

Comment: if you installed m2 from the archive you will find the file in `vendor/magento-catalog/view...`

Answer (score 0):

List of all SKUs:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity`;
```

List of all product names:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
```

As Mr. Jute explains in his blog post [List of Product tables in magento](https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/list-of-product-tables-in-magento/):

> Main table for products in magento:
>
> > catalog_product_entity
>
> Above table is an act as main table, for that child tables are staring with “catalog_product_entity_” prefix.
>
> > catalog_product_entity_datetime – Product – date attribute are stored here. Ex: New From, New To
> >     catalog_product_entity_decimal – Product price related values.
> >     catalog_product_entity_gallery
> >     catalog_product_entity_int – Product Status, Visiblity etc..
> >     catalog_product_entity_media_gallery – product images path, Thumb , small, etc
> >     catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value – Product image,product image position,  title info & position of image info, etc
> >     catalog_product_entity_tier_price – Product tier product
> >     catalog_product_entity_varchar – Product name, URL, etc
> >     Bundled product – information: Will get bundled product associated values from below table
> >     catalog_product_bundle_option
> >     catalog_product_bundle_option_value
> >     catalog_product_bundle_selection
>
> Related to downloaded product information.
>
> > catalog_product_link
> >     catalog_product_link_attribute
> >     catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
> >     catalog_product_link_attribute_int
> >     catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar
> >     catalog_product_link_type
>
> Product custom option information will get from below tables
>
> > catalog_product_option
> >     catalog_product_option_price
> >     catalog_product_option_title
> >     catalog_product_option_type_price
> >     catalog_product_option_type_title
> >     catalog_product_option_type_value
>
> Configurable product and Grouped product information will get it from below tables
>
> > catalog_product_super_attribute;
> >     catalog_product_super_attribute_label;
> >     catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing;
> >     catalog_product_super_link;
> >
> > catalog_product_enabled_index;
> >     catalog_product_website – Product website
>
> Product currency inventory information: (Inventory)
>
> > cataloginventory_stock
> >     cataloginventory_stock_item
> >     cataloginventory_stock_status – Currently Product is instock or outof stock
> >
> > catalog_category_product – Relationship between categorty & product. What ant all product are mapped with which category also the possition of product under the category